# How a webservice provide by OSB can be called as soon as we receive a message in Websphere MQ?

Tags: ibm-mq, oracle-service-bus

I am using IBM Websphere Message Queue. I want webservices provided by Oracle Service Bus to be called as soon as message queue receives a new message. How can I configure this?

TIA,

Arpan Chaudhury

Comment: To do that, something would have to read the message off the queue and call the web service.  Since OSB can directly read the queue, why would you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While creating OSB Proxy Service, use MQ as Protocol and provide the MQ details. Whenever there will be a message pushed into the Queue, OSB Proxy Service will get invoked.